# Normal coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I was wondering if this is a legitimate way to define the induced basis of the tangent space in normal coordinates.

So the exponential map is a diffemorphism $exp:U \subset T_pM \rightarrow V \subset M.$ Then I assume that $\partial_i|_{exp(tR)}= Dexp(tR)(e_i)$ where $(e_i)$ is a fixed basis of the tangent space and $t \mapsto tR$ is a line in $U.$

Now my question is: Does this really define the induced basis of $T_{exp(tR)}M$?

Comment: It does, as $D \exp$ is nondegenerate in the normal coordinate.

Comment: What's so special about the exponential map? This is how one defines the frame of $TV$ induced by any parametrization.

Comment: @John thank you. so can we additionally say that if our manifold $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ then the components of the metric tensor are $g_{i,j}|_{\exp(tR)} = \langle \partial_i |_{\exp(tR)}, \partial_j|_{\exp(tR)} \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^n}$

Comment: exp is defined independent of how $M$ is sitting inside $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @John okay, not sure if I understand this. I was just wondering whether this approach to compute the components of the metric tensor is valid? Cause I don't know how to compute the metric tensor in normal coordinates at least theoretically?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @John I want to understand how the metric tensor looks at different positions on the manifold in these normal coordinates or at least: How it is defined there?

Comment: It is **not** known what's $g_{ij}$ even for normal coordinate, except at the origin, where we have $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ and $\partial_k g_{ij} = 0$ (both only at the origin)

Comment: @John But this is somewhat strange, cause when you think of a parametrized surface $F: U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ then the metric tensor is given by $(g_{i,j})= DF^T DF.$ If you know that your manifold sits in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ why can't you define $(g_{i,j}) =Dexp^T Dexp$? This looks reasonable cause at the origin, the derivative of the exponential map is the identity, which would give you also the identity for the metric tensor (just as you explained)

Comment: Yes, of course you can do that, **theoretically**. But when you think of how exp is defined (via geodesics), the explicit calculation $Dexp^TDexp$ is simply impossible.

Comment: @John ah, so the definition is correct, but we just can't compute this. Thank you very much, that's all I wanted to know.